# Difficulty with high value integers

Tags: c++

Well i have encountered a strange problem. 
I was given a task to print the smallest pair of three numbers whose Greatest Common Divisor was the highest within a range of [0-N],N is provided by user.
My code is very well applicable for a great deal of numbers but i think it is unable to process very large values .

Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   

long long  n; // THE RANGE 
long long  t; // THE NUMBER OF TEST CASES.
cin>>t; 
for(long long  i=0; i <t ; i++)
  {   cin>>n;
      if(n<3)
      {
          cout<<"-1"<<endl;
      }
       long long  gcd=0;    //GREATEST COMMON DIVISOR .
      if(n>=3)
      {
      for(long long  j=1 ; j<=n ;j++  )
      {   long long  cool=0;
          for(long long  k=j; k<=n; k++)
          {
              if(k%j==0)
              {
                  cool++;
              }
          }
          if(cool>=3)
          {
               gcd=j;
          }
      }
      cout<<endl;
      long long  count=0;
      for(long long  l= 1 ; l<=n ;l++)
        {
          if(l%gcd==0)
          {   cout<<l<<" ";
              count++;
          }
          if(count==3)
          {
              break;
          }
        }
      }

  }

return 0;
}
```

Although i have used long long , it is unable to process inputs which are 15 digits long . Any assistance is apprciated . such as:

33333407 66666814 100000221
170438383717 340876767434 511315151151
151827062727 303654125454 455481188181
50606060603 101212121206 151818181809
770506172727 1541012345454 2311518518181
17172705050 34345410100 51518115150
4050572729393 8101145458786 12151718188179
5050606060 10101212120 15151818180
5050628283 10101256566 15151884849
184050508505050 368101017010100 552151525515150

Comment: What do you mean *It runs out of compilation time*?  Are you doing a code competition and you are getting TLE or error that it takes to long?

Comment: `It runs out of compilation time .` What? I dont know of any compiler that has a time limit...

Comment: sorry guys , it is unable to process

Comment: it means it  fails to produce output , which is that the compiler just sits there which black window and no results

Comment: 1) Compilation time can, in no way, be impacted by the input, since you can only provide input to a program, once it is compiled. 2) "_that the compiler just sits there which black window and no results_" Once again, once you get to run your program, compiler is no longer running. 3) If your code works correctly, and you only want to increase its performance, [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better place for such a question.

Comment: i have investigated and found out it can store upto 19 digits yet my code fails.

Comment: @KshitijDhyani I think youre confusing what the compiler actually is. If youre getting a command prompt for *your* process than the compiler did finish. The compiler takes your source code and makes an executable with it, if youre running that then the compiler is no longer involved.

Comment: okay thank you my friend

Comment: Signed integer overflow is UB. If that is what you are asking.

Comment: what do u mean by this can u please explain @Ron

Comment: You may check which is the biggest value a `long long` can hold using `std::numeric_limits`. If you need bigger numbers you'll have to use a non standard library.

Comment: thank you so much @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Ron Hi, BTW. Bored at Shannon airport :-/

Comment: If you want more digits you will need a big integer library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your run times are unacceptably long. Look at your code:

```
for(long long j=1 ; j<=n ;j++ )
{ 
    long long cool=0; 
    for(long long k=j; k<=n; k++) 
    { 
        if(k%j==0) { cool++; }
    }
```

What is the complexity of this?  If n=1,000,000,000, then how many times will it run the inner block:

```
if(k%j==0) { cool++; }
```

My suggestion is to find an O(1) way to get the same result as without looping:

```
long long cool=0; 
for(long long k=j; k<=n; k++) 
{ 
   if(k%j==0) { cool++; }
}
```

You have other inefficiencies, which will still make your code unacceptably slow. For 15 digit numbers, even O(n) is too slow. Figure out how to avoid iterating over all `n` values. You have two such loops, which will have to be replaced, or terminated early.

Comment: Thanks man , thank you for your guidance,i will follow what u say ,